# SQL Server - Column for Time Since Last Row Was Created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is structured like this

```
CREATE TABLE log (
  id                 BIGINT            IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  datetime_created   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
  message            VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

I'd like to add a fourth column, `time_since`, that by default looks at the previous row's `datetime_created` field and gets the difference in time and saves this in the new row's `time_since` column.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: As a note, I'm constrained to using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Looks like you need an insert trigger, but the definition of "previous row" is a bit nebulous in a database.  If you mean `id - 1`, there are scenarios (deleted row, failed insert statement) where that id might not exist.

Comment: Not necessarily `id - 1`, just literally the last row in the table

Comment: There is no *last row* in a relational table, but you might use `MAXdatetime_created)`

Comment: What is the definition of "previous row"?   Or, based on your comment, what is the definition of "last row in the table"?

Comment: @dnoeth - What do you mean there is no last row? A table has a clustered index and a clustered index is sorted. Seems like there is a last row in table

Comment: @Aducci: A relational table is a bag of rows. And even in the physical implementation the *last row* has no meaning as there's no way to access it.

Comment: @dnoeth SELECT TOP 1 datetime_created FROM log order by datetime_created desc - you got last row in this meaning ;-)
to Steve
But if we look at concurrent environment then there is last row visible to current transaction regarding its isolation level! but maybe exists newer record not already committed - question is useless in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a column for this, I recommend that you just calculate it on the fly using **LAG**.  That way if the dates ever change you won't need to change this 2nd field.

## Example:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
  id                 BIGINT            IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  datetime_created   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
  message            VARCHAR(MAX)
)

insert into log values ('2016-01-01', 'first');
insert into log values ('2016-01-02T12:21:23', 'second');

SELECT l.id, l.datetime_created, l.message, DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(l.datetime_created) OVER (ORDER BY l.id), l.datetime_created)
FROM log l
```

Comment: Apologies, I should've mentioned that I'm forced to use SQL Server 2008. But this looks great for 2012+!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an instead of trigger

```
create table log
(
    id bigint identity(1, 1) primary key,
    datetime_created datetime not null default (getdate()),
    message varchar(max),
    time_since int not null
)
go

create trigger is_log on log
instead of insert
as
    insert into log (datetime_created, message, time_since)
    select datetime_created, message, 
        datediff(ss, isnull((select max(datetime_created) from log), getdate()), datetime_created)
    from inserted
go

insert into log (message) 
values ('Message 1')

waitfor delay '00:00:02';

insert into log (message) 
values ('Message 2')

waitfor delay '00:00:04';

insert into log (message) 
values ('Message 3')

waitfor delay '00:00:06';

insert into log (message)
select message + 'multi insert'
from log
go

select *
from log
```

Answer (score 0):

When inserting a new row, why not also insert a value that equals DATEDIFF(SECOND, (SELECT MAX(datetime_created) FROM log), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)